# Замена элемента массива, хранящегося в ячейке БД

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в в БД данные хранятся в виде

```
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"}
```

Если я правильно понимаю, то это строка ?

Существует ли способ как мне заменить значение только 1 элемента этого массива?

На данный момент я представляю себе это только так:
Вытаскиваю всю строку, преобразую ее в массив, меняю то что мне нужно, преобразую обратно в строку и запихиваю в ячейку обратно.

Можно ли сделать это проще?

Comment: это сериализованный json-объект

Comment: возомжно вам поможет какой нить `update t set x = JSON_SET(x, '$.a', '0') where = ..` чтобы заменить значение `a`

Comment: начиная с версии 5.7.8

Comment: *заменить значение только 1 элемента этого массива* Укажите точно, что Вы намерены искать, на что менять, и что получить в итоге. А вообще - [MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  JSON Function Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html).

Comment: @teran вариант с update сработал так как мне нужно, спасибо!

Comment: тогда оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

начиная с версии 5.7.8 в mysql появилось множество [функций для работы с JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html).
вам, видимо, пригодятся функции `JSON_SET` или `JSON_REPLACE`, и в общем случае запрос на обновление поля `a` объекта в столбце `f` будет иметь вид:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET f = JSON_SET(f, '$.a', 'new value')
WHERE ...
```